# Dlang: get names of all superclasses for an instance as array

Tags: oop, inheritance, reflection, d

I can get the full class name of an instance with fullyQualifiedName, but how can I get the fullyQualifiedNames of all it's superclasses? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [std.traits.BaseClassesTuple](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#BaseClassesTuple).

```
import std.traits, std.stdio, std.meta;

class A {}
class B: A{}
class C: B{}

void main(){
    auto instance = new C;
    static foreach(T; AliasSeq!(typeof(instance), BaseClassesTuple!(typeof(instance))))
        writeln(fullyQualifiedName!T);
}
```